# Write Privileges - localhost - Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost, privileges

I'm new to the mac world and have just been setting up my webserver. I used the following guide: https://alan.ivey.dev/posts/2011/os-x-10.7-lion-development-native-mamp-with-mysql-installer/

I've transferred my sites and databases and everything is going pretty well. The only problem I have is with the writing permissions. For example there is a config file that needs to be written to, and I had to right click, go to Get Info then enable read & write for staff and everyone.

I can't manually go through and enable these write privileges for every file/folder. I didn't need to do this using WAMP and made development much quicker.

So wondering about 2 possible solutions: 
a) add my user account to a whitelist for the localhost so that 644 privileges are sufficient
b) set the write privileges recursively

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I found the best solution was to change the apache user and group settings. The instructions can be found at: http://paulmason.name/item/change-apache-user-group-in-lion-os-x

1. Open Terminal and Enter

   ```
   sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
   ```
2. Find and change http.conf code from

   ```
   User _www
   Group _www
   ```

   To

   ```
   User your_mac_username
   Group staff
   ```

   Note: With earlier versions such as Leopard, capitalize staff to Staff. You can get your username and group by typing "id" and hitting enter in terminal
3. Restart Apache

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```

Comment: Easiest solution! Both the user and apache get write/read permissions without changing the permissions ;-)

Comment: why it's ]so important to put the the Group as staff ? I work on linux and on mac, on linux the group is the username but on mac I had to out staff to make it work otherwise Apache won't start.

Comment: Upgrading to macOS Sierra overwrote my `User` and `Group` values in httpd.conf to `_www` and `_www`. Your answer helped me resolve the permission issue I was encountering by setting the owner of the directory in question to the `User` and `Group` of these new values.

Comment: Worked great. Note to others: each update resets this.

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

I'm the author of the mentioned blog post. For web server file permissions, you'll want to give write access to the _www user for files. For config.inc.php, you would set it a couple ways:

Have _www own the file and have write permissions:

```
$ sudo chown _www config.inc.php
$ chmod u+w config.inc.php
```

Have your user own the file, change the group to _www, and give group write permissions:

```
$ sudo chgrp _www config.inc.php
$ chmod g+w config.inc.php
```

Or, if you feel comfortable allowing all users to write, which I would not recommend for security reasons, give all users the ability to write:

```
$ chmod a+w config.inc.php
```

If an entire folder needs to be written by the _www user, it can own the folder and all files:

```
$ sudo chown -R _www:_www folder/
```

or you can give the folder write and execute permissions by all:

```
$ chmod a+wx folder/
```

The reason why `chmod 774` gave you forbidden errors was because the _www user fell under the '4' permission, which is 'read-only.' For directories, a user needs 'execute' in order to traverse into the folder. `chmod 775` would allow user and group to rwx, and others to r-x. [Here's more information on Unix file permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).

Also, your user could retain full ownership and add certain permissions for the _www user instead of changing the level of access for ALL users by using Access Control Lists.

```
$ sudo chmod -R +a '_www allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' folder
$ sudo chmod +a '_www allow read,write' config.inc.php
```

If you're going to go the route of ACLs, I'd suggest doing some more reading to see what levels of access you really need to provide. [Here is a great place to start](http://www.ideocentric.com/technology/articles/title/osx-acl).

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. Just wondering why I would change the owner of config.inc.php and where can I find it?

Comment: @alanthing Couldn't it be risky to grant permissions to apache to write (any?) files on your machine?

Answer (score 10):

I'm running Apache on OSX and this fixed it for me:

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www <mywebfolder>
sudo chmod -R 775 <mywebfolder>
```

---

Update #1:

Syntax: `sudo chown <user>:<group> <file-or-folder>`. The Apache user on OSX is `_www`.

To keep ownership but give Apache r-w-x permissions:

```
sudo chown -R <your-username>:_www <mywebfolder>
sudo chmod -R 775 <mywebfolder>
```

---

Update #2:

I like this method best. Set Apache to run as you.

1. In terminal type `id` to get `uid=123(Myname)`.
2. Open /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and edit it to use your username.

   ```
   <IfModule unixd_module>
      User Myname
      Group staff
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Back to terminal: `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: this caused mamp to stop for me. Not found a fix yet but its messy.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend settings the Write privileges recursively for your web root.

You can do this via the console / terminal using `chmod -R 774 /my/web/root`. For me, the owner and group is set to: `www-data:myUserName`, which can be set by using `chown`. Don't forget to check who's your web user first.

**Edit:** For better understanding, why you don't have access:

Chmod 774, each number stands for specific rights: user, group, others. If the user is set to `www-data` and the group to `www-data` (most users on a Unix system are in a group that's named by their username). So, if you're not in the group `www-data` you either have to join it, or you have to change owner (chown) or you have to change the permissions (chmod). There are several tutorials out there, for more information.

Comment: I just tried `chmod -R 774` for one of my sites and it made the whole site forbidden until I used `chmod -R 777` which doesn't seem right. Any ideas? Also I don't know how to check who my web user is, can you please explain?

Comment: You also have to check the owner of a file (user ls -l for this). Mostly the folders are set to `www-data:www-data`. Which means, you're not mentioned and you don't have access until you use `chmod 777`. The last 7 stands for "others". Just set the owner as I mentioned in my answer. I'll edit my answer to explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions didn't work for me. What I did was :

Right click the folder -> Get Info

[image]

There is a priviledge setting at the very bottom.

Change it to **Read & Write** for **Everyone**.